# PulseAudio undefined symbol after compiling from source

Tags: raspbian, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up my new RPI2 as a hub for my home automation projects. I am new to linux so please bear with me if this is a simple thing, I couldn't find a solution after a day of troubleshooting. Problem is, I've been trying to compile PulseAudio-raop2 to stream music to my AirPort Express. It compiles, but after running installing and running, it complains the following.

```
pulseaudio: symbol lookup error: pulseaudio: undefined symbol: pa_dbus_connection_unref
```

As for the installation, I just do the following:

```
sudo ./bootstrap
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I figure this is some kind of linking error though I have no idea how to solve this or even begin to search for the issue.

Here is the fork I am trying to install: https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2. I am running the suggested version of Raspbian from the official Raspberry site.

Comment: Unless you understand what you are doing it is sensible to only use software from the standard repositories.  Why do you need this variant?

Comment: I need it to get AirPlay streaming support for my Raspberry's audio, as it is quite a distance away from my speakers. I'm actually trying to follow a guide posted here but it doesn't really work as described: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/redirect-audio-to-another-airplay-device. I tried the standard pulseaudio-module-raop-discover but it resulted in horrible stuttering when streaming the music. My AirPort Express is quite new so I figured it might make sense to try the new one as it provides support for the new AirPlay.

Comment: It probably installed some libraries.  Did you run `ldconfig` afterward?  Check the executable with `ldd` (e.g. `ldd /usr/local/bin/pulseaudio`) to make sure everything its linked to is actually found by the linker.

Comment: I did run ldconfig. I tried ldd and it doesn't seem to list any errors, just a bunch of different libraries. Here's the output: [ldd output](http://pastebin.com/GaXkD0Cv)