# Choppy sound on MPD + Airplay, working pulseaudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, shairplay

My current setup is mpd server on a RPi connected via pulseaudio to an airport express sink which in turn is connected to my receiver/amp as described in [Redirect audio to another AirPlay device](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/redirect-audio-to-another-airplay-device)

In this setup I get choppy sound coming from the receiver. However, I have troubleshooted the problem to mpd because of the following:

1) It is not a pulseaudio + raop since running `ffmpeg -i my-audio-file.mp3 -f pulse "my-sink.local"` does play well through the receiver via airplay.

2) It is not an issue of connectivity of mpd since connecting to mpd either with mpc locally or a client from a different computer plays well when mpd is configured to use the alsa sink and a headset on the RPi.

I suppose it is some form of buffering on mpd that is conflicting with airplay/raop but I do not know where to look, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

Use

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. This fixes the choppy audio

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time trying to configure Airplay through Raop/PulseAudio on the new Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian Jessie with very little success.  I would highly recommend [forked-daapd](https://ejurgensen.github.io/forked-daapd/):

> This is a much updated version of the original forked-daapd 0.19, a Linux/FreeBSD DAAP (iTunes) media server with support for AirPlay devices, Apple Remote (and compatibles), MPD, Spotify, mp3 streaming and internet radio.

Install was very straightforward and I had the  whole  thing up and running in about 10 minutes.  Here are the install instructions as detailed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49928):

```
1a. If you use Jessie then add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb http://www.gyfgafguf.dk/raspbian jessie/armhf/
or
1b. If you use Wheezy then add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb http://www.gyfgafguf.dk/raspbian wheezy-backports/armhf/
2. Run sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install forked-daapd
3. Edit the config file /etc/forked-daapd.conf and (re)start the server with sudo /etc/init.d/forked-daapd restart

Optional - how to add support for Spotify:
1. Add deb http://apt.mopidy.com/ stable main contrib non-free to /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Run sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install libspotify-dev
3. Restart forked-daapd and enter credentials as described in the instructions.
4. Check the log to see how it is working. It should start loading your playlists.
```

Comment: Your post has been flagged automatically as "duplicate answer". The thing with that is: if both questions are answerable by the exact same answer one of them should be closed as a dupe to the other. Unless of course your answer can be edited/changed/expanded to address an issue specific to this question.